# Concyclic points from other concyclic points

Tags: geometry

Trying to prove that points a,b,c,d are concyclic:
I've proven that a,c,d,e(a new point) are concyclic, and that b,a,c,f(another new point) are concyclic, and also that d,e,b,f are concyclic. None of the points are co-linear. Can I use this information to prove a,b,c,d are concyclic?

Comment: No. Consider the "Venn diagram" arrangement of three circles. They intersect at six points, which can be labeled in such a way that the first three quadruplets are concyclic as specified, but $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are not.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can make no such conclusion:

[image: Counterexample]